# How to Dynamically add a button from the .py file to a single screen of a screen manager in .kv file

Tags: python, json, dynamic, kivy

How can I dynamically add a button to a particular screen of my .kv file's screenmanager? The problem is, the buttons that get created show up on all screens.

I have a program I am working on that will allow the user to input there particular conditions and calculate ACFM. I am currently trying to set up a file screen that allows the user to create multiple files. I am trying to allow one main button called "create new file" creates more buttons on the first screen. The problem is, the buttons that get created show up on all screens.

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
import Functions as f1
from kivy.uix.button import Button
Window.size = (300,625)
window_x = Window.width
window_y = Window.height

Builder.load_file("main.kv")

class counter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 2
    def increase(self):
        self.count += 1
b = counter()

class Calc(FloatLayout):
    def testbutton(self,instance):
        btn = Button(text = "testing123", color = (1,1,1,1),
                     size_hint =(.5,.05),
                     pos = (0,(window_y-(window_y*(.07+(b.count*.05)))))
                     )
        b.increase()
        self.add_widget(btn)

    # define the multiplication of a function
    def calculate(self, instance):
        f = float(self.flow.text)
        p = float(self.pressure.text)
        t = float(self.temperature.text)
        sg = float(self.specific_gravity.text)
        self.acfm.text = str(f) #str(f1.ACFM(f,p,t,sg)) I commented this out for the purpose of posting this in my questions.

class test(App):
    def build(self):
        return Calc()

if __name__=="__main__":
    test().run()
```

main.kv

```
<calc>:
    flow: _flow
    pressure: _pressure
    temperature: _temperature
    specific_gravity: _specific_gravity
    acfm: _acfm
    FloatLayout:
        ScreenManager:
            id: screen_manager
            size: self.size
            Screen:
                name: "filescreen"
                FloatLayout:
                    canvas:
                        Color:
                            rgb: 1,1,1
                        Rectangle:
                            size: self.width, self.height
                            pos: self.pos
                    AnchorLayout:
                        anchor_x: 'center'
                        anchor_y: 'top'
                        Label:
                            canvas.before:
                                Color:
                                    rgb: 1,1,1
                                Rectangle:
                                    size: self.size
                                    pos: self.pos
                                Color:
                                    rgb: 0,0,0
                                Line:
                                    width: 1
                                    rectangle: self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height
                            size_hint: 1,.07
                    FilescreenButton:
                        text: "Create New File"
                        pos: 0,root.height-(root.height*(.07+.05))
                        on_press: root.testbutton(*args)
            Screen:
                name: "solverscreen"
                GridLayout:
                    cols:1
                    size_hint: 1,1
                    ScrollView:
                        FloatLayout:
                            canvas:
                                Color:
                                    rgb: 1,1,1
                                Rectangle:
                                    size: self.width, self.height
                                    pos: self.pos
                            size_hint: 1,1.5
                            GridLayout:
                                cols:1
                                spacing: 1
                                pos_hint: {"top": (1),"left": 1}
                                size_hint: .4, None
                                row_default_height: root.height*.05
                                Label:
                                    text: "Inputs"
                                    color: 0,0,0,1
                                    canvas.before:
                                        Color:
                                            rgb: 1,1,1
                                        Rectangle:
                                            size: self.width,self.height
                                            pos: self.pos
                                CustomLabel:
                                    text: "Flow"
                                CustomLabel:
                                    text: "Pressure"
                                CustomLabel:
                                    text: "Temperature"
                                CustomLabel:
                                    text: "Specific Gravity"
                                Label:
                                    text: "Results"
                                    color: 0,0,0,1
                                    canvas.before:
                                        Color:
                                            rgb: 1,1,1
                                        Rectangle:
                                            size: self.width,self.height
                                            pos: self.pos
                                Button:
                                    text: "Calculate"
                                    on_press: root.calculate(*args)
                            GridLayout:
                                cols:1
                                spacing: 1
                                pos_hint: {"top": (1),"right": .7}
                                size_hint: .3, None
                                row_default_height: root.height*.05
                                Label:
                                    canvas.before:
                                        Color:
                                            rgb: 1,1,1
                                        Rectangle:
                                            size: self.width,self.height
                                            pos: self.pos
                                TextInput:
                                    text: "0"
                                    id: _flow
                                TextInput:
                                    text: "0"
                                    id: _pressure
                                TextInput:
                                    text: "0"
                                    id: _temperature
                                TextInput:
                                    text: ".6"
                                    id: _specific_gravity
                                Label:
                                    canvas.before:
                                        Color:
                                            rgb: 1,1,1
                                        Rectangle:
                                            size: self.width,self.height
                                            pos: self.pos
                                Label:
                                    id: _acfm
                                    color: 0,0,0,1
                                    canvas.before:
                                        Color:
                                            rgba: .7,.7,.7,1
                                        Rectangle:
                                            pos: self.pos
                                            size: self.size
                                        Color:
                                            rgb: 1,1,1
                                        Line:
                                            width: 1
                                            rectangle: self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height
                            GridLayout:
                                cols:1
                                spacing: 1
                                pos_hint: {"top": (1),"right": 1}
                                size_hint: .3, None
                                row_default_height: root.height*.05
                                Label:
                                    canvas.before:
                                        Color:
                                            rgb: 1,1,1
                                        Rectangle:
                                            size: self.width,self.height/2
                                            pos: self.pos
                                CustomButton:
                                    text: "MMSCFD"
                                CustomButton:
                                    text: "PSIG"
                                CustomButton:
                                    text: "F"
                                CustomButton:
                                    text: "SG"
                                Label:
                                    canvas.before:
                                        Color:
                                            rgb: 1,1,1
                                        Rectangle:
                                            size: self.width,self.height
                                            pos: self.pos
                                CustomButton:
                                    text: "ACFM"
        AnchorLayout:
            anchor_x: 'left'
            anchor_y: 'bottom'
            GridLayout:
                cols: 4
                size_hint: 1,.05
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgb: 1,1,1
                    Rectangle:
                        size: self.size
                        pos: self.pos
                Button:
                    text: "Files"
                    on_press: screen_manager.current = 'filescreen'
                Button:
                    text: "Solver"
                    on_press: screen_manager.current = 'solverscreen'
<CustomLabel@Label>:
    #font_size: (((self.width*5)+(self.height))/6)*.12
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: 0,0,0
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
<CustomButton@Button>:
    background_color: .25,.25,.25,1
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: .25,.25,.25,1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
        Line:
            width: .09
            rectangle: self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height
<FilescreenButton@Button>:
    size_hint: .5,.05
    color: 0,0,0,1
    background_color: 1,1,1,0
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 0,0,0
        Line:
            width: 1
            rectangle: self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height
```

I am not getting any error messages. I just want the dynamically created buttons from the .py file to only go to one screen of the .kv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently adding it to the Calc FloatLayout which is the root and each screen is a child of this root. If you want to add it to just one screen, than you need to call the add_widgets function of that specific screen.

One option is via an id

change kv file like below

```
        Screen:
            id: id_solverscreen
            name: "solverscreen"
```

change py file like below

```
self.ids.id_solverscreen.add_widget(btn)
```

python file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
Window.size = (300,625)
window_x = Window.width
window_y = Window.height

Builder.load_file("main.kv")

class counter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 2
    def increase(self):
        self.count += 1
b = counter()

class Calc(FloatLayout):
    def testbutton(self,instance):
        btn = Button(text = "testing123", color = (1,1,1,1),
                    size_hint =(.5,.05),
                    pos = (0,(window_y-(window_y*(.07+(b.count*.05)))))
                    )
        b.increase()
        self.ids.id_solverscreen.add_widget(btn)

    # define the multiplication of a function
    def calculate(self, instance):
        f = float(self.flow.text)
        p = float(self.pressure.text)
        t = float(self.temperature.text)
        sg = float(self.specific_gravity.text)
        self.acfm.text = str(f) #str(f1.ACFM(f,p,t,sg)) I commented this out for the purpose of posting this in my questions.

class test(App):
    def build(self):
        return Calc()

if __name__=="__main__":
    test().run()
```

kv file

```
<calc>:
    flow: _flow
    pressure: _pressure
    temperature: _temperature
    specific_gravity: _specific_gravity
    acfm: _acfm
    FloatLayout:
        ScreenManager:
            id: screen_manager
            size: self.size
            Screen:
                name: "filescreen"
                FloatLayout:
                    canvas:
                        Color:
                            rgb: 1,1,1
                        Rectangle:
                            size: self.width, self.height
                            pos: self.pos
                    AnchorLayout:
                        anchor_x: 'center'
                        anchor_y: 'top'
                        Label:
                            canvas.before:
                                Color:
                                    rgb: 1,1,1
                                Rectangle:
                                    size: self.size
                                    pos: self.pos
                                Color:
                                    rgb: 0,0,0
                                Line:
                                    width: 1
                                    rectangle: self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height
                            size_hint: 1,.07
                    FilescreenButton:
                        text: "Create New File"
                        pos: 0,root.height-(root.height*(.07+.05))
                        on_press: root.testbutton(*args)
            Screen:
                id: id_solverscreen
                name: "solverscreen"
                GridLayout:
                    cols:1
                    size_hint: 1,1
                    ScrollView:
                        FloatLayout:
                            canvas:
                                Color:
                                    rgb: 1,1,1
                                Rectangle:
                                    size: self.width, self.height
                                    pos: self.pos
                            size_hint: 1,1.5
                            GridLayout:
                                cols:1
                                spacing: 1
                                pos_hint: {"top": (1),"left": 1}
                                size_hint: .4, None
                                row_default_height: root.height*.05
                                Label:
                                    text: "Inputs"
                                    color: 0,0,0,1
                                    canvas.before:
                                        Color:
                                            rgb: 1,1,1
                                        Rectangle:
                                            size: self.width,self.height
                                            pos: self.pos
                                CustomLabel:
                                    text: "Flow"
                                CustomLabel:
                                    text: "Pressure"
                                CustomLabel:
                                    text: "Temperature"
                                CustomLabel:
                                    text: "Specific Gravity"
                                Label:
                                    text: "Results"
                                    color: 0,0,0,1
                                    canvas.before:
                                        Color:
                                            rgb: 1,1,1
                                        Rectangle:
                                            size: self.width,self.height
                                            pos: self.pos
                                Button:
                                    text: "Calculate"
                                    on_press: root.calculate(*args)
                            GridLayout:
                                cols:1
                                spacing: 1
                                pos_hint: {"top": (1),"right": .7}
                                size_hint: .3, None
                                row_default_height: root.height*.05
                                Label:
                                    canvas.before:
                                        Color:
                                            rgb: 1,1,1
                                        Rectangle:
                                            size: self.width,self.height
                                            pos: self.pos
                                TextInput:
                                    text: "0"
                                    id: _flow
                                TextInput:
                                    text: "0"
                                    id: _pressure
                                TextInput:
                                    text: "0"
                                    id: _temperature
                                TextInput:
                                    text: ".6"
                                    id: _specific_gravity
                                Label:
                                    canvas.before:
                                        Color:
                                            rgb: 1,1,1
                                        Rectangle:
                                            size: self.width,self.height
                                            pos: self.pos
                                Label:
                                    id: _acfm
                                    color: 0,0,0,1
                                    canvas.before:
                                        Color:
                                            rgba: .7,.7,.7,1
                                        Rectangle:
                                            pos: self.pos
                                            size: self.size
                                        Color:
                                            rgb: 1,1,1
                                        Line:
                                            width: 1
                                            rectangle: self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height
                            GridLayout:
                                cols:1
                                spacing: 1
                                pos_hint: {"top": (1),"right": 1}
                                size_hint: .3, None
                                row_default_height: root.height*.05
                                Label:
                                    canvas.before:
                                        Color:
                                            rgb: 1,1,1
                                        Rectangle:
                                            size: self.width,self.height/2
                                            pos: self.pos
                                CustomButton:
                                    text: "MMSCFD"
                                CustomButton:
                                    text: "PSIG"
                                CustomButton:
                                    text: "F"
                                CustomButton:
                                    text: "SG"
                                Label:
                                    canvas.before:
                                        Color:
                                            rgb: 1,1,1
                                        Rectangle:
                                            size: self.width,self.height
                                            pos: self.pos
                                CustomButton:
                                    text: "ACFM"
        AnchorLayout:
            anchor_x: 'left'
            anchor_y: 'bottom'
            GridLayout:
                cols: 4
                size_hint: 1,.05
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgb: 1,1,1
                    Rectangle:
                        size: self.size
                        pos: self.pos
                Button:
                    text: "Files"
                    on_press: screen_manager.current = 'filescreen'
                Button:
                    text: "Solver"
                    on_press: screen_manager.current = 'solverscreen'
<CustomLabel@Label>:
    #font_size: (((self.width*5)+(self.height))/6)*.12
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: 0,0,0
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
<CustomButton@Button>:
    background_color: .25,.25,.25,1
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: .25,.25,.25,1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
        Line:
            width: .09
            rectangle: self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height
<FilescreenButton@Button>:
    size_hint: .5,.05
    color: 0,0,0,1
    background_color: 1,1,1,0
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 0,0,0
        Line:
            width: 1
            rectangle: self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height
```

Comment: This fixed my problem perfectly. Thank you!